# Mostrar registros, através de consulta PHP e MySQL, em duas tabelas, com o GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, group-by

Boa Noite....
Tenho as seguinte dúvida
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este sistema tem como objetivo, trazer os usuarios de uma determinada região ou locais de trabalho que pertencessem  a determinada cidade.

Se buscarmos pela city=4261, de acordo com o código que fiz, ele retornara:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No entando, o João tem mais um local de atendimento, que é o Posto, mas não esta aparecendo por causa do agrupamento. Como faço para mostrar todos os locais que o João atende, idempendente se é da mesma cidade?

Segue o código da busca

```
<?php
$form=4261;
$search_user = "SELECT
u.id u_id,u.first_name u_first_name, u.city u_city,  
uw.user uw_user, uw.workplace uw_workplace, 
w.id w_id, w.city w_city, w.name w_name 
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN users_has_workplaces AS uw
ON u.id=uw.user 
LEFT JOIN workplaces AS w 
ON w.id=uw.workplace
GROUP BY u_first_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
";
$result_user = mysqli_query($conn, $search_user);
while($row_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_user)){
    echo $row_user['u_first_name']."<br>";
    echo $row_user['w_name'];
    echo "<hr>";
} 
?>
```

Comment: Já pensou em fazer um UNION das consultas que tratam separadamente de cada condição?

Comment: Nunca utilizei o UNION, vou dar uma estudada, e ver se soluciona meu problema. Obrigado pela sugestão.

Comment: Se você quer que os dois registros apareçam, porque está usando agrupamento?

Comment: Você pode dar `GROUP BY` em mais de uma coluna, no seu caso local/cidade de trabalho `GROUP BY u_first_name, w_city, w_name`, dessa forma irá agrupar apenas os resultados iguais, quando as 3 colunas forem iguais.

Comment: Neste ponto que surgiu meu problema. Pois foi a única forma (neste momento) que encontrei, de não mostrar registros repetidos. No exemplo de busca que publiquei, caso não utilize o agrupamento, ele vai me retornar duas vezes o João. Quero que mostre apenas uma vez o nome dele, com os dois locais de atendimento abaixo do nome. Não sei se utilizar uma condicional seria a maneira mais corretam, gostaria da opinião dos colegas.

Answer (score 0):

Como eu disse no comentário, você pode tentar agrupar por mais de uma coluna, fazendo assim você consegue mostrar os dois resultados do João.Os resultados serão agrupados primeiro por col1(u_first_name) e, em seguida, por col2(w.city). No MySQL, a preferência de coluna vai da esquerda para a direita.

```
<?php
    $form=4261;
    $search_user = "SELECT u.id u_id, 
           u.first_name u_first_name, 
           u.city       u_city, 
           uw.USER      uw_user, 
           uw.workplace uw_workplace, 
           w.id         w_id, 
           w.city       w_city, 
           w.name       w_name 
    FROM   users AS u 
           LEFT JOIN users_has_workplaces AS uw 
                  ON u.id = uw.USER 
           LEFT JOIN workplaces AS w 
                  ON w.id = uw.workplace
    WHERE uw.workplace = '$form'
    GROUP  BY u_first_name, 
              w.city, 
              w.name
    HAVING Count(*) > 0";

    $result_user = mysqli_query($conn, $search_user);

    while($row_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_user)){
        echo $row_user['u_first_name']."<br>";
        echo $row_user['w_name'];
        echo "<hr>";
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Gnomo. Vou ter que tentar criar uma condicional dentro do WHILE para mostrar os workplaces  de acordo com o usuário. Muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Eu sente falta de um WHERE ali, você pode usar para filtrar os workplaces e usuários, antes de ir para o WHILE.

Comment: Editei ali em cima adicionando um WHERE, se der certo, não esquece de marcar a pergunta como correta.